# Reading a Python generated SQLITE file into SQLITE

Tags: python, database, sqlite, import

So I generated a simple sqlite database called example.db with a table called wasp in Python.

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE wasp
         (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date TEXT, x INTEGER, y INTEGER, z INTEGER, temp INTEGER, bat INTEGER)''')
```

I was able to use Python to add data and read the data. Now I want to import this file in SQLITE using the command line. I installed sqlite3 on linux and am trying to use the `.import` function but `.import example.db wasp` generates an error. It says wasp is not a table. It's a table in the `example.db` file but it's not a table within sqlite. So I recreated the table within sqlite and ran the command again, same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use the `.import` command to read the table you created from python. The `.import` command is intended to import tabular text data ([CSV data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)).

The python `sqlite` module however writes native SQLite database files. Just open the `example.db` file with the sqlite3 command:

```
$ sqlite3 example.db
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
wasp
```

Comment: Look at ".dump" if you want to move a table from one db file to another.